# Internet not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: networking, ubuntu, internet

I have a dedicated server which I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 10.04 to 10.10 (it was running the LTS version), and it had seemed to have upgraded successfully until I tried to access the internet in a browser. I was unable to access any websites (although I am able to ping) and it seems there is no outgoing connection at all to the web, yet I can connect to my server remotely via SSH and remote desktop tools such as NoMachine. I checked the network devices available, and it shows three:

lo (Loopback)

eth0

eth1

I checked eth0 and it seems to be working, with my server IP and it is active and sending & receiving packets normally, yet I am still unable to access the internet.

Looking at the Network Connections window on the Wired Connections tab, there is only a "Auto eth1" connection, but shouldn't there be an "Auto eth0" as that is the connection it seems my server should/is using? Is a matter of changing the default connection of Ubuntu to eth0 to access the internet?

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have an ip address.. sounds like DNS problems..

Try this..  ( im guessing the DIG will fail )

```
dig google.com
ping 74.125.77.147
```

Ping works???.. good

edit your /etc/resolv.conf / add this at the bottom

```
nameserver 141.1.1.1
```

save the file

**Run those commands again :D**

and let me know

Comment: @Arenstar Perhaps I should edit my post when I said I was unable to ping: When I used the Network Tools to ping it did not work, but when I used the terminal it pinged successfully. Also you are correct, dig did not work and timed out.

Comment: updated my answer! :D

Comment: @Arenstar Wow, as simple as that! Thank you so much! Works perfectly :) Thanks again.

Comment: Note that `141.1.1.1` is a public DNS server run by Cable & Wireless Worldwide. I like to use Google's (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) because (somewhat surprisingly given Google's general data-collection habits), they have a good privacy policy (https://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/intro.html). I'm not sure what C&W's privacy policy is for their name server for non-customers.

Comment: @mattdm.. this true.. hehe ( im not sure either )

Comment: @Joel.. no problem, glad to help. You should consider using a different DNS server ( perhaps of your ISP ). 141.1.1.1 was for debugging purposes only..